Science fiction movie about parallel universe
I am searching for a quite long time a movie that was about an English (I think) professor, or sort of researcher who knew word that can lean you to another universe. So no one believed him (of course) but in some way he found a way to open the portal. 
The scene about the portal I remember quite well. It's him in a place like cave, reminds me of Grand Canyon, when he was saying the words (each sentence made sense in the situation) and he was jumping through the rocks or staying in one place depending on the "poem".  
So he entered the word, and after that I don't really remember anything. 
It was kind of an action, Jackie Chan movie, the bad guys were ninjas, there were samurais with swords, they were teaching the professor how to be a warrior.
There were actions in Chinese places and there were this beautiful woman (also chinese) which I think had love interest with the proffessor. 
I know this is not much info, but please help me, I was really impressed by the movie when I was a kid. So I guess the movie is made definitely before 2006, maybe even before, I am not sure.

is it asian movie?

Maybe, but the main character was american and some of the action was in America.
I am sorry, for not being very helpful on this, but i watched it before 10 or maybe more years ago...

Mortal Combat maybe?

No... but thanks to you i found it! The film has very similar vibe to the one i watched so I started watching similar trailers in youtube and i found it!

It's the Lost Empire (Monkey king) :)

@Eliza Glad you found it! You can post an answer to your own question if you wanted to.

The OP, from the comments, notes that she found the film in question after someone suggested Mortal Combat. Specifically:

The film has very similar vibe to the one I watched so I started watching similar trailers on youtube and I found it!
It's the Lost Empire (Monkey king).

Possibly, it's this two-part TV mini-series from 2001 (Links to imdb.com, amazon.com; Note the Amazon link is currently for a Region 2 DVD). I can't find another reference to something that's known as "Lost Empire"/"Monkey King"

This sounds like the movie "John Carter (from Mars)".

The scene about the portal I remember quite well. It's him in a place
  like cave, reminds me of Grand Canyon, when he was saying the words
  (each sentence made sense in the situation) and he was jumping through
  the rocks or staying in one place depending on the "poem".

John Carter is a Civil War veteran in 1868 who is summoned to fight the indians but has no interest and desserted the army. When he is being chased he hides in some cave where he encounters someone holding a medaillion. As the person is dying he is whispering some words. John touches the medaillion as he dies and is being transported to a different planet, Mars. 

So he entered the word, and after that I don't really remember
  anything. It was kind of an action, Jackie Chan movie, the bad guys
  were ninjas, there were samurais with swords, they were teaching the
  professor how to be a warrior. There were actions in Chinese places
  and there were this beautiful woman (also chinese) which I think had
  love interest with the proffessor.

When he arrives at Mars, it doesn't take long for him to be captured by the alien green creatures, the Tharks, who have a tribal and primitive life style and force him to fight for his life. Which you probably remember as "ninjas". 

The OP found the movie, it was (and I quote him from the comments: "It's the Lost Empire (Monkey king"

@M.Polo probably her ;)
